# Mongodb search function not executing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using react, nodejs and mongodb. I have a search bar that sends a post request to a search function that then querys mongodb and returns the result. The problem is that the function is never getting executed.

*React:*

```
const getData = (searchValue) => {
const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source();
async function fetchPost() {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.post(`/search`, {
      params: { searchValue },
      cancelToken: ourRequest.token,
    });
    if (response.data) {
      console.log(response.data);
    } else {
      dispatch({ type: 'notFound' });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('There was a problem or the request was cancelled.');
  }
}
fetchPost();
};
```

*Express:*

router.js

`apiRouter.post('/search', postController.search);`

postController.js

```
exports.search = function (req, res) {
  Post.search(req.body.searchTerm) 
    .then((posts) => {
      console.log('Hello..');
      res.json(posts);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      res.json([]);
    });
};
```

Post.js:

```
Post.search = function (searchTerm) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof searchTerm == 'string') {

       console.log('hello..', searchTerm) // nothing

       let posts = await Post.reusablePostQuery([
         { $match: { $text: { $search: searchTerm } } },
         { $sort: { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } },
       ]);
      resolve(posts);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
};
```

When I enter a search I get a empty array response in the dev console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always hard to troubleshoot questions like this as there could be an issue in so many places. But I will point to a few that stand out and hopefully it will lead you to the answer.

The first thing that jumps out is this: `req.body.searchTerm`. You're looking for the `searchTerm` while your React app isn't sending it. Instead you're sending `searchValue` as in `params: { searchValue }` which translates to `params: { searchValue: searchValue }`.

So you should change 2 things in your React code.

1. Send a body with your request.
2. Use proper nomenclature so your backend app can see it.

```
const response = await Axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/search',
  data: {
    searchTerm: searchValue
  },
  cancelToken: ourRequest.token
})
```

These changes, in theory, should resolve your issue.